# CodeIgniter Multidimensional Object - ActiveRecord

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

I have an object called 'events', that's created via $data['events'] = function (the function pulls information out of an events table and others using active record).

The events object looks like:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [course_name] => Course 3
                [course_description] => Course
                [course_price] => 995
                [supplier_name] => Supplier 3
                [location_country_code] => GB
                [location_country] => United Kingdom
                [location_city] => London
                [venue_name] => Venue 2
                [venue_address] => 2 Street
                [venue_postcode] => EC2M 7PQ
                [venue_city] => London
                [venue_county] => 
                [venue_country] => United Kingdom
                [venue_locality] => 
                [event_type] => Materials Only
                [event_status] => Confirmed
                [course_id] => 2
                [event_duration] => 3
                [event_start_date] => 2013-09-12
                [event_date_added] => 2013-02-26 14:36:06
                [event_status_id] => 2
                [event_type_id] => 4
                [tutor_id] => 0
                [tutor_confirmed] => 0
                [event_featured] => 0
                [event_push] => 0
                [event_active] => 0
                [invigilator_id] => 0
                [event_discount] => 
                [event_max_delegates] => 16
                [location_id] => 1
                [venue_id] => 1
                [supplier_id] => 2
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [course_name] => Course Name
                [course_description] => Course Description
                [course_price] => 995
                [supplier_name] => Supplier 1
                [location_country_code] => GB
                [location_country] => United Kingdom
                [location_city] => London
                [venue_name] => Venue Name
                [venue_address] => Street
                [venue_postcode] => EC2M 7PQ
                [venue_city] => London
                [venue_county] => 
                [venue_country] => United Kingdom
                [venue_locality] => 
                [event_type] => Private Venue
                [event_status] => Provisional
                [course_id] => 1
                [event_duration] => 3
                [event_start_date] => 2013-11-13
                [event_date_added] => 2013-02-26 09:56:17
                [event_status_id] => 1
                [event_type_id] => 3
                [tutor_id] => 0
                [tutor_confirmed] => 0
                [event_featured] => 0
                [event_push] => 0
                [event_active] => 0
                [invigilator_id] => 0
                [event_discount] => 395
                [event_max_delegates] => 16
                [location_id] => 1
                [venue_id] => 1
                [supplier_id] => 1
            )

    )
```

I'd like to add a nested object under the key 'delegates' for each row using ActiveRecord, that pulls through the delegates attached to the event using a bridge table 'events_delegates_bridge' by comparing the 'event_id' and 'delegate_id columns in that table.
 Essentially so that the object looks like so:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [course_name] => Course 3
                        [delegates] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 1
                                                        [name] => Joe Bloggs
                                                    )
                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 2
                                                        [name] => Joe Smith
                                                    )
                                                [3] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 3
                                                        [name] => Jane Doe
                                                    )
                                            )
                [course_description] => Course
                [course_price] => 995
                [supplier_name] => Supplier 3
                [location_country_code] => GB
                [location_country] => United Kingdom
                [location_city] => London
                [venue_name] => Venue 2
                [venue_address] => 2 Street
                [venue_postcode] => EC2M 7PQ
                [venue_city] => London
                [venue_county] => 
                [venue_country] => United Kingdom
                [venue_locality] => 
                [event_type] => Materials Only
                [event_status] => Confirmed
                [course_id] => 2
                [event_duration] => 3
                [event_start_date] => 2013-09-12
                [event_date_added] => 2013-02-26 14:36:06
                [event_status_id] => 2
                [event_type_id] => 4
                [tutor_id] => 0
                [tutor_confirmed] => 0
                [event_featured] => 0
                [event_push] => 0
                [event_active] => 0
                [invigilator_id] => 0
                [event_discount] => 
                [event_max_delegates] => 16
                [location_id] => 1
                [venue_id] => 1
                [supplier_id] => 2
            )
                )
```

Any ideas how best to achieve this? Thanks.

**Event Model**
    class Event_Model extends CI_Model {

```
    public function get_events() {

        $this->db->select( '*' );
        $this->db->from( 'courses' );
        $this->db->from( 'suppliers' );
        $this->db->from( 'locations' );
        $this->db->from( 'venues' );
        $this->db->from( 'event_type' );
        $this->db->from( 'event_status' );
        $this->db->join( 'events', 'events.course_id = courses.id AND events.supplier_id = suppliers.id AND events.location_id = locations.id AND events.venue_id = venues.id AND events.event_type_id = event_type.id AND events.event_status_id = event_status.id', 'inner' );
        $this->db->order_by( 'events.event_start_date', 'asc' );
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

**Dashboard Controller**
    $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_events();

**Delegates Model**
I've created this to get the delegate data. Do you think it can be used to add the correct delegates to the events object?

```
class Delegate_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_delegates() {

        $this->db->select( '*' );
        $this->db->from( 'delegates' );
        $this->db->from( 'events_delegates_bridge' );
        $this->join( 'delegates', 'delegates.id = events_delegates_bridge.delegate_id', 'inner' );
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

**Just tested this and it shows a blank page.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best off doing it with 2 separate queries.

```
$events = array();
$result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM events WHERE ...');
foreach($result->result_array() as $event) {
    $events[$event['id']] = $event;
}

$result = $this->db->query('
    SELECT * FROM events_delegates_bridge 
    JOIN delegates ON (delegate_id = delegates.id)
    WHERE ...
');
foreach($result->result_array() as $delegate) {
    if (!empty($events[$delegate['event_id']])) {
        $events[$delegate['event_id']]['delegates'][] = $delegate
    }
}
```

This bit of code just queries the events and puts them in an array indexed by the event id.
Then, a separate query runs to pull up the delegates, and attaches them to the appropriate event.

Comment: I want to use active record though?

Comment: You can replace the `->query()` bits with their active record equivalents if you want.

Comment: I've edited my question adding the event model and the $data object in the dashboard controller so you can see how I'm pulling through the events. How would I go about integrating what you have explained? I'm pretty new to CodeIgniter.

Answer (score -1):

use `$name=$variable->result_array();var_dump($name);` I think This work

Comment: It's not really a solution, it doesn't explain anything to me?

Comment: ok , in your model change this --

return $query->result();

to 

return $query->result_array();

it return $query data as a array().

Comment: I'm trying to add another object to a 'delegates' key in the events object that will contain all the delegates associated with that event.